# OpenWRT: How to log port probing at WAN physical port

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, logging, openwrt

I have set up a webserver from within my LAN with virtual segregation through a DMZ. I installed a firewall for the DMZ with appropriate port forwarding and traffic rules.

On the server I run a vanilla Apache2 installation for testing purposes (I also tried a SimpleHTTP Python server). I checked, that the server is connected to the correct port on the router :) - it is isolated from the LAN.

I tried to connect to the server from another WAN IP and did a port probe trough [grc.com/shieldsup](http://grc.com/shieldsup). My own connection is without result and GRC lists port 80 as closed, all others as stealth.

In attempt to tackle the problem I now want to see how the OpenWRT router handles the incoming request on port 80 or if it receives the request at all. How could I do this?

---

[image: Port Forwarding Rules]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did it by enabling logging for the WAN zone in the routers firewall and thereby discovered that I had set a static `source port` in the port forwarding rule, requiring a TCP request outgoing on port 80 from the client side, which is utter nonsense, as all browsers chose a random upper port for their requests and 80 is bound to root privileges and reserved for server usage.

```
Network -> Firewall -> General Settings (Zones) -> Edit Button of WAN zone -> Advanced Settings -> Enabling Logging of this zone
```

Logs are from then on written to `Status -> Kernel Log`